# When 'reduce' a list, after using 'coalesce' function, how to mutate a new variable?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When using 'reduce' combine a list to 'final_0' (refer below image),
how to mutate new variable 'amount_from'?  my code show error . Thanks!

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
table_base <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b","c","d"))

table_a <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b"),
                      value=c(1,2))

table_b <- data.frame(cat=c("a","c","d"),
                      value=c(7,9,10))

final_0<- reduce(list(table_base,table_a,table_b),left_join,by='cat') %>% 
  mutate(amount=coalesce(!!!select(.,starts_with('value'))))
```

#below code show error [no applicable method for 'fill' applied to an object of class "character"]

```
final_0 %>% pivot_longer(-c('cat','amount')) %>% 
  mutate(value_from=if_else(amount==value,name,NULL)) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  mutate(value_from=tidyr::fill(value_from,.direction = "downup"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `?fill` will show the issue:

> **Usage** `fill(data, ..., .direction = c("down", "up", "downup", "updown"))`

The function takes a data frame and a set of columns to fill (from `...`). In your implementation, you used it inside a `mutate()` call.
Here's how to fix the issue:

```
final_0 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c('cat','amount')) %>% 
  mutate(value_from=if_else(amount==value,name,NULL)) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  fill(value_from, .direction = "downup")

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   cat [4]
  cat   amount name    value value_from
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     
1 a          1 value.x     1 value.x   
2 a          1 value.y     7 value.x   
3 b          2 value.x     2 value.x   
4 b          2 value.y    NA value.x   
5 c          9 value.x    NA value.y   
6 c          9 value.y     9 value.y   
7 d         10 value.x    NA value.y   
8 d         10 value.y    10 value.y
```

Although this works, there is a solution that that avoids unnecessarily creating `NULL` values using `if_else()` and then needing to fill them:

```
final_0 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("cat", "amount")) %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(value_from = na.omit(name[amount == value]))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   cat [4]
  cat   amount name    value value_from
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     
1 a          1 value.x     1 value.x   
2 a          1 value.y     7 value.x   
3 b          2 value.x     2 value.x   
4 b          2 value.y    NA value.x   
5 c          9 value.x    NA value.y   
6 c          9 value.y     9 value.y   
7 d         10 value.x    NA value.y   
8 d         10 value.y    10 value.y
```

Some important notes about this:

- We simply filter on `name` using your `if_else()` condition. We then apply `na.omit()` since `value` could be `NA`.
- This code can result in different values of `value_from` for the same `cat` in the case that `value.x` and `value.y` are both equal to `amount`. This would also happen in your implementation because of the way you used `if_else()`. If you want `value_from` to only have one value for each `cat`, you should use something like `na.omit(name[amount == value])[[1]]` in the code above.